# Go use init method inside multiple function

Tags: go, dependency-injection

I’ve the following go code which works, im creating a VTS property which is used in some files under the same package

File `A` is creating `VTS` which should be used in all of the functions below (in different files under the same package)

File A

```
package foo

var VTS = initSettings()
func initSettings() *cli.EnvSettings {
    conf := cli.New()
    conf.RepositoryCache = "/tmp"
    return conf
}
```

In file B im using it like

```
package foo

func Get(url string, conf *action.Configuration) (*chart.Chart, error) {

    cmd := action.NewInstall(conf)
    // Here see the last parameters 
    chartLocation, err := cmd.ChartPathOptions.LocateChart(url, VTS)
    return loader.Load(chartLocation)
}
```

File C

```
package foo

    func Upgrade(ns, name, url string, vals map[string]interface{}, conf *action.Configuration) (*release.Release, error) {
        
    … 
        if url == "" {
            ch = rel.Chart
        } else {
            cp, err := client.ChartPathOptions.LocateChart(url, VTS)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
    
            ch, err = loader.Load(cp)
        }
```

And in additional files under the same package.
Is there a **cleaner way** to initiate the VTS and use it in different files instead of package variable ?

I've tried something like

```
func Settings() *cli.EnvSettings {
    cfg := cli.New()
    cfg.RepositoryCache = "/tmp"
    return cfg
}
```

and pass it as param but I got error

```
func GetChart(url string, Settings func(), cfg *action.Configuration) (*chart.Chart, error) {
```

Comment: You could always pass `VTS` to the dependent functions as an argument. It makes unit testing simpler as well.

Comment: @AlexanderGuyer , could you please provide an example how can I do it? as this is function is a bit confusing

Comment: Sure; see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `*cli.EnvSettings` as an additional parameter to`Get()` and `Upgrade()`, and then have the caller pass `VTS` as an argument.

**File A**

```
package foo

func initSettings() *cli.EnvSettings {
    conf := cli.New()
    conf.RepositoryCache = "/tmp"
    return conf
}
```

**File B**

```
package foo

func Get(url string, conf *action.Configuration, vts *cli.EnvSettings) (*chart.Chart, error) {

    cmd := action.NewInstall(conf)
    // Here see the last parameters 
    chartLocation, err := cmd.ChartPathOptions.LocateChart(url, vts)
    return loader.Load(chartLocation)
}
```

**File C**

```
package foo

func Upgrade(ns, name, url string, vals map[string]interface{}, conf *action.Configuration, vts *cli.EnvSettings) (*release.Release, error) {
    … 
    if url == "" {
        ch = rel.Chart
    } else {
        cp, err := client.ChartPathOptions.LocateChart(url, vts)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        ch, err = loader.Load(cp)
    }
```

**File D: Some other file of a higher level package**

```
...
vts := foo.initSettings()
foo.Get(myUrl, myConf, vts)
```

Of course, if you want to call `foo.Get()` or `foo.Update()` from several other files and packages throughout your project, and if you want all of those calls to use the same `*cli.EnvSettings` object, you'll likely have to construct `VTS` from a higher level and pass it around through more functions (i.e. continue the pattern).

In general, this is a form of [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), where `foo.Get()` and `foo.Update()` are the "clients" and `VTS` is the "service". One big advantage of function parameters over package variables is testability. It is difficult to test how `foo.Get()` behaves with different `*cli.EnvSettings` objects if said `*cli.EnvSettings` object is a global / package variable. It's far easier for the tests to decide what `*cli.EnvSettings` objects to use, and then pass them to `foo.Get()`.

One disadvantage of this pattern is that you can end up with functions with many parameters if they require many injected services, and they can become a bit unwieldy. However, if a function or object truly depends on many services that are truly independent, then there's really no work-around to this anyways. It's usually better to have a function with many parameters than a function that is very difficult to test.